# android-cts-8.1_r3 execution is not starting

Tags: android, cts, android-cts

On starting, facing the below issue[followed all the precondition steps]

```
03-29 04:49:11 W/DynamicConfigPusher: Cannot download and parse json config from URL https://androidpartner.googleapis.com/v1/dynamicconfig/suites/CTS/modules/CtsMediaStressTestCases/version/8.1_r3?key=AIzaSyAbwX5JRlmsLeygY2WWihpIJPXFLueOQ3U
03-29 04:49:11 I/MediaPreparer: Instrumenting package android.mediastress.cts.preconditions.app:
03-29 04:49:17 I/MediaPreparer: Downloading media files from https://dl.google.com/dl/android/cts/android-cts-media-1.4.zip
03-29 05:01:42 E/ModuleDef: TargetSetupError in preparer: com.android.compatibility.common.tradefed.targetprep.MediaPreparer
03-29 05:01:42 E/ModuleDef: Precondition class com.android.compatibility.common.tradefed.targetprep.MediaPreparer failed
03-29 05:01:44 I/MediaPreparer: Instrumenting package android.mediastress.cts.preconditions.app:
03-29 05:01:50 I/MediaPreparer: Downloading media files from https://dl.google.com/dl/android/cts/android-cts-media-1.4.zip
```

This is happening continuously. No test case run

Answer (score 0):

I think it would require you to download and install android-cts-media-1.4.zip and install it to your Android hardware in order to proceed the mediastress test cases:

- Go on that page https://source.android.com/compatibility/cts/downloads ; scroll down to the bottom of the page, download the media 1.4 package.
- Unzip and go to the android-cts-media-1.4. Then try bellow command on terminal

  ./copy_media.sh [your_resolution_param_here]

The resolution param is not required, if you don't put it it will add all the media file in, thus may potentially lead to some failure test cases. But you should probably check again what's your maximum media resolutions allowance via CDD document for your particular Android version. Here are the list of storage options to be brief:

- 480x360: 98MB
- 720x480: 193MB
- 1280x720: 606MB
- 1920x1080: 1863MB

Comment: No, it is not solving the issue.

Comment: Tried copying the downloaded media file to /tmp in host. now its not going for the above download.

Comment: did you try to follow steps described in setup cts webpage? https://source.android.com/compatibility/cts/setup. It asked to turn on several setting options and installing 2 apks, if your device is 7.0 version

Comment: Hi , my device version is android-cts-8.1_r3

Answer (score 0):

Copy a android-cts-media-1.4.zip to /tmp/android-cts-media/ will fix the issue